# Cannot run ssis packages because 64-bit dtexec is not installed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dtexec

I've been able to successfully create an ssis package (.dtsx) file using the SSMS 'import data' option and the VS 2017 SSIS toolbox (SQL Server 2017). The package itself works and it reads a csv file and loads it into a database table. Simple. This is on windows 10.

I'm trying to run these packages on Win Server 2012 R2 (Azure VM) command line and it won't work (it does work from VS 2017) because the dtexec.exe files are all 32 bit. For the life of me I cannot get a 64 bit dtexec.exe file installed.

*I've tried*

1. the same procedure on windows 10 and it works. I create the package and then I can run it via dtexec /f "path to .dtsx"
2. I've tried to set the run time to 32 bit per (
   [SSIS 64 bit vs 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855169/ssis-64-bit-vs-32-bit))
   But this is not an option in either the SSMS import data tool or VS 2017 SSIS Toolbox settings/properties.
3. I've come across this page
   (https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-execute-an-ssis-package-from-the-command-line-or-a-batch-file)
   But I'm not sure that turning this package into a 'package deployment model' is the way to go.
4. I've tried copying the 64bit dtexec and related files to the Win 2012 R2 machine but the dll and code is not registered.
5. When I try to install SSMS or SQL Express on the server I don't get options for customizing the install.

I've confirmed that the server is 64-bit.

I've tried an azure logic app but I simply don't like it that way.

*These are some of the errors I'm seeing*

> Code: 0xC001700A
>
> Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The
>   version number cannot be greater than current version number.
>
> Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154

I would like to keep things simple and create an ssis package that can then be run at the server via a command line script that is scheduled. Why in the world is this so hard to set up on an Azure VM running Windows Server 2012 R2?

Below are a couple of more resources I've stumbled upon. Looks to me that the VS 2017 SSIS toolbox way of doing this is what MS wants people to use. How could it be that they make it so easy to create the workflow and store that into a package (the dataflow works on the Win 2012 R2 server inside of VS 2017) but when it comes time to roll it out and automate it everything falls apart? I must be missing something. Any help would be useful. How the hell do I tell VS 2017 to create a 32-bit compliant version of this package?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-7-adding-and-configuring-the-ole-db-destination?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: SSIS is a feature of SQL Server. It's installed by SQL Server's setup program. The options you tried don't even mention SQL Server though. *Is* SQL Server installed on that VM? Did you install the SSIS feature?

Comment: Is the question perhaps `How can I run SSIS packages on a machine that doesn't have SSIS` ? Or is it perhaps `How can I run SSIS packages withouth paying either for a SQL Server license or the managed Azure SSIS service`? SSIS is a component of SQL Server so installing it on another server requires an extra server license. Azure offers a managed SSIS service so you *don't* really need a separate VM

Comment: _It won't work because the dtexec.exe files are all 32 bit_ Why can't you run it as 32 bit? _via a command line script that is scheduled_ why not do what almost everyone else does and run it in a SQL Agent job? You need to install SQL Server anyway to be licenced and to install SSIS properly. It's difficult to understand the real root of your problem here.

Comment: I suspect the first issue is that you have built a package against the 2017 format and are trying to get that to run against a 2012 version of binaries (The exact error messages would confirm this). If this is the case, within the SSIS project, click the project and change the target to SQL Server 2012. Then to confirm/deny the existence of dtexec, open a command prompt and type `cd \ ` and then `dir /s /b dtexec.exe` and update your question with the results from there

Comment: All, thank you very much for your comments. The very first thing that I did was to install SQL Server Management Studio 18, not SQL Server.
I just changed the TargetServerVersion to 'SQL Server 2012' in VS 2017 and rebuilt the project. When I try to run the package via 'dtexec /f "path to .dtsx"

Comment: When running dtexec.exe I get the message:  
Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154

Comment: Is this ['managed SSIS service'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure) what one of the responses was referring to? I mean, seriously, why would you want to go through with this 75+ step procedure when it can literally be replaced by a single batch command provided your server has SQL Server/dtcexec 64bit?

Comment: You know you can edit your question to post all those errors, right?

Comment: Everyone commented correctly that [you need a SQL Server license](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server-Support/Running-SSIS-packages-outside-the-Developer-tools-using-DTEXEC/ba-p/318873) to run all of the features of SSIS dtexec.exe utility.  
I just want to point out that I installed SQL Server Express 2017 in the VM and was able to run the .dtsx packages successfully. These packages are merely 1. reading a .csv file, 2. deleting the corresponding table and 3. inserting all of the records. This is like a bulk insert where the data file is NOT local to the server.

Comment: Thank you all. One last thing to add is that the ```cd \``` and ```dir /s /b``` tip proved to be very helpful. I have 9 different dtexec.exe files due to SQL server express(32/64 bit), SSMS and Visual Studio installations. You have to find the right one and use it to run the .dtsx packages.